# Codecover plugin and eclipse - fatal error

Tags: eclipse, code-coverage

I installed [CodeCover](http://codecover.org/) to my STS so I can use it in my project. I can run code cover and get the measurments, but there is one thing that is bothering me.

If I enable code cover for a given project, everytime when I make a change to a source file and then save it I get this error message:

```
[FATAL]An error occured when trying to compile instrumented sources
```

if there are some errors reported by eclipse validator in some project file. Can I disable this feature, because it is really frustrating that I save one file and I get bit message that there are errors, even if I can see them underlined red by the editor.

Comment: Which coverage plugin exactly did you install?

Comment: Code cover is the name:http://codecover.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a bug, I suggest you file a bug at the project web-site, or try to fix it yourself by getting the [source](http://codecover.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/codecover/).

Comment: I took a peek at the bug reports for code cover and it seems that I wasn't the only one, the development for this plugin stopped about two years ago. I will try EclEmma plugin. As far as I can see it still has active development community.